# Compare ipv4 addresses in ipv6 notation

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

On incoming connections via ipv4 the `IPAddress` is in ipv6 notation such as `::ffff:1.2.3.4`

I want to compare these addresses to an `IPAddress` I get from elsewhere which is in ipv4 notation: 1.2.3.4

By notation I mean an `ipv4.GetAddressBytes()` return 4 bytes whereas `ipv6.GetAddressBytes()` return 16 bytes.

Is there an easy way to convert the ipv4 `IPAddress` to ipv6 notation?

I think I know how to do it byte by byte but I might miss something and would rather use an existing function if there is any.

Comment: Can you take the IPv4 part from your v6 source and compare to the other "native" IPv4? e.g. `::ffff:1.2.3.4` => **1.2.3.4**

Comment: Yes either way works since I'm only going to compare them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantate your ip addresses as instances of `System.Net.IPAddress`. The look at the following methods:

- `IPAddress.Equals()`
- `IPAddress.MapToIPv4()`
- `IPAddress.MapToIPv6()`

You'll probably want to add special handling for special addresses (such as the TCP/IP loopback adapter: That is a single IPv6 address, `::1`, while for IPv4, even though the most commonly used address for that purpose is `127.0.0.1`, the IETF has reserved the **entire**  127/8 block (`127.0.0.0`–`127.255.255.255` inclusive) for that purpose. How you determine equality (or even equivalency) is debatable.

Since IPv4 and IPv6 are completely different and independent addressing schemes, one might reasonably argue that the only true way of determining equivalency is if they both map to the same endpoint (MAC address/network adapter).

Comment: `.MapToIPvX()` was exactly what I was looking for. In my case network adapters is not an issue since I'm comparing incoming connections with a DNS record.
You might add that the map methods are only available in the 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the IPv4 part from your "source" and compare to your "destination" IPv4, like the below sample

```
IPAddress ipv6 = null;
IPAddress ipv4 = null;
IPAddress testIp = null;

IPAddress.TryParse("::ffff:1.2.3.4", out ipv6);
IPAddress.TryParse("1.2.3.4", out ipv4);

string ipString = ipv6.ToString();
IPAddress.TryParse(ipString.Substring(ipString.LastIndexOf(":") + 1), out testIp);
// this will return false
Console.WriteLine("ipv4 == ipv6 : " + (ipv4.Equals(ipv6)).ToString());
// this will return true
Console.WriteLine("ipv4 == testIp : " + (ipv4.Equals(testIp)).ToString());
```